# WHERE conditions in query using two columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, where-clause

My question is better explained by the following example:

```
select * 
from PEOPLE
WHERE
  NAME like @SearchString OR
  SURNAME like @SearchString OR
  NAME + SURNAME like @SearchString OR
  SURNAME + NAME like @SearchString
```

Basically which is the exact syntax for:

```
NAME + SURNAME like @SearchString OR
SURNAME + NAME like @SearchString
```

? (I want to be able to search in 2 fields at the same time)

Imagine the case where `@SearchString = 'John Doe'`

Thanks.

**Update**:
to better express myself what i mean is that the following query returns no results, even if JOHN DOE is in the table

```
declare @searchstring varchar(100)
set @searchstring = 'John%Doe'

select * 
from PEOPLE
WHERE
  NAME + SURNAME like @searchstring
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what your issue is, do you want just to avoid much lines of code ?

Comment: no, i do not know how to let a user type "John Doe" and I use this string to search in two fields (NAME and SURNAME). In this case NAME + ' ' + SURNAME = 'JOHN DOE'. But I do not know how to say this in the where condition. what i wrote above is ok as syntax but does not work

Comment: Space is causing issues? NAME + ' ' + SURNAME like @SearchString works better?

Comment: How about @SearchString LIKE NAME + '%' + SURNAME

Comment: Please see the Update above

Comment: Sorry, i see it works,  so my question is: is that approach correct? I mean doing "WHERE  NAME + SURNAME  like" is a viable solution?

Comment: i decided to answer my own question so the solution can be of use to other people who is trying to achieve this, after 10 years of using sql server it is the first time i stumble upon this feature of concatenating fields with the + operator in the where clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trial and error I realized the syntax

```
WHERE NAME + SURNAME like @SearchString
```

is correct and works fine. May be it is an overhead in some cases but it works fine in a normal (no big data) scenario.

For the pleasure of sharing I write here the query i used inmy real application (a web application that returns a list of people where the user just has one editbox to search: so he can search "John D", "Doe John", "John", "Doe", ...):

```
declare @searchstring varchar(100)
set @searchstring = 'John Doe'

SELECT *
FROM PEOPLE 
WHERE ( (SURNAME LIKE @SearchString) OR
       (NAME LIKE @SearchString) OR
       (NAME + ' ' + SURNAME LIKE @SearchString) OR
       (SURNAME + ' ' + NAME LIKE @SearchString))
```